# Is it possible to listen to multiple ports in Caddy 1.x with the same setting?

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

For example, instead of:

```
:81 {
  tls /etc/xxx/xxx.crt /etc/xxx/xxx.key
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080 {
    transparent
  }
}
:82 {
  tls /etc/xxx/xxx.crt /etc/xxx/xxx.key
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080 {
    transparent
  }
}

...

:443 {
  tls /etc/xxx/xxx.crt /etc/xxx/xxx.key
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080 {
    transparent
  }
}
```

Can we do something like:

```
:81 - 443 {
  tls /etc/xxx/xxx.crt /etc/xxx/xxx.key
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080 {
    transparent
  }
}
```

OR even:

```
:81, :82, :83, ..., :443 {
  tls /etc/xxx/xxx.crt /etc/xxx/xxx.key
  proxy / 127.0.0.1:8080 {
    transparent
  }
}
```